# How to store the token in Local or session storage in android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, local-storage, sessionstorage

I'm creating an app that interacts with SOAP web-services to get data from the database. When the user successfully logins it generates a token via web-services.  This token will be needed later on in other activities to call web-service methods. My question is, how can I pass on that token to the next activity when its needed and maintain it until the user logs out.

MainActivity.java

SharedPreferences preferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("YourSessionName", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("name",AIMSvalue);

```
                    editor.commit();
```

OtherActivity.java

```
    SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("YourSessionName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();

    token=preferences.getString("name","");

    editor.commit();
```

Comment: I think [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is right place

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: What problem you are getting when using SharedPreferences ?

Comment: please put your code here first

Comment: what do you mean by SharedPreference not working. Its an app level storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CommonUtilities {

    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static Context mContext;

/**
     * Create SharedPreference and SharedPreferecne Editor for Context
     *
     * @param context
     */
    private static void createSharedPreferenceEditor(Context context) {
        try {
            if (context != null) {
                mContext = context;
            } else {
                mContext = ApplicationStore.getContext();
            }
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(IConstants.SAMPLE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

/**
 * Put String in SharedPreference Editor
 *
 * @param context
 * @param key
 * @param value
 */
public static void putPrefString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    try {
        createSharedPreferenceEditor(context);
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Use this **putString()** method to store a token when you logged in. And remove that token when you logged out or token expires.

Comment: I have done this but not working. It always treats it as a new request when called second method of web service after login is called i.e the token generated from login screen is not properly getting passed to another screen.@ Kush Patel