# how can i put session on my app so that i don't need to login again after closing the app?

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication

i am making a login page where if user logged in for order ,he can order his request etc,even after the closing of app if he opens the app again he doesnt  need to login again..i have facebook button also but that is other thing...kindly help?
here is my code :

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String eml;
    private String pswrd;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status = "";
    private Button fbbutton;
    Profile profile;
    Button login;

    // private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    TextView tac1;
    EditText email, pass;
    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud.....com/broccoli/login.php";
    public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Get_hash_key();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);





       // AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        fbbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbtn);

        fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call private method
                onFblogin();
            }
        });

        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        tac1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cAcc);

        tac1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                                {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {


                                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, RegistrationForm.class));


                                    }
                                }

        );

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lbtn);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                eml = email.getText().toString();
                pswrd = pass.getText().toString();


                // new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));
                                    //your intent code here
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username/password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("email", eml);
                        params.put("password", pswrd);

                        return params;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            }

        });
    }


    public void Get_hash_key() {
        PackageInfo info;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.zeba.broccoli", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md;
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                Log.e("hash key", something);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
            Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception", e.toString());
        }
    }




    private void onFblogin() {
        callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        try {
                            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                                        // profile2 is the new profile
                                        profile = profile_new;
                                        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                                    }
                                };
                                mProfileTracker.startTracking();
                            } else {
                                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                            }

                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                            Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                                            // Application code
                                            try {
                                                String fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                                String fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                                String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                                String fb_gender = object.getString("gender");
                                                String fb_email = object.getString("email");
                                                String fb_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                            //use shared preferences here
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();


                            //go to Home page
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                        }
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Log.d(TAG_CANCEL, "On cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        //Log.d(TAG_ERROR, error.toString());
                    }



                    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                        callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    }
                });




    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

p.s i am new to android so gives answers with coding and try to replace my code with ur correct code...thx in advance

Comment: use sharedpreference

Comment: can u help me through coding as to where i shud put my code n what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417124/how-to-store-the-token-in-local-or-session-storage-in-android/40417397#40417397 refer this question

Comment: create Sharedpreference object. when user logged in your app, and success msg appears. put boolean value in sharedprefs to true. next time app start, check  that boolean value. if it is true then procced to next activity or show login screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain session in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678669/how-to-maintain-session-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

You can use shared preferences, save your user name in your shared preferences,
and put check on the main launching activity (for example if you login activity as launcher activity), if username exists then redirect user to some other activity using intent otherwise ask user to login again.

Hope it helps you.

when I login for the very first time i did this after login(read about shared preferences if you don`t know how to use it)

```
CommonObjects.saveSharedPreferences(Login.this, "user_id", user_id);
CommonObjects.saveSharedPreferences(Login.this, "name", name);
```

this i close my app and open app again, hence my login activity is the first activity which always shows first when i open my app, then in very beginning of the of the login activity do this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (CommonObjects.hasSharedPreference(context,"user_id")){
            Intent intMain=new Intent(Login.this,DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intMain);
            finish();
        }
}
```

hope you understand now.

Comment: please help through coding

Comment: its ok ,i got the answer

Comment: can u replace ur code with mineso tht i can check it properly

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
        private String eml;
        private String pswrd;
        private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String status = "";
        private Button fbbutton;
        Profile profile;
        Button login;

        // private int serverResponseCode = 0;
        TextView tac1;
        EditText email, pass;
        private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud.....com/broccoli/login.php";
        public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            Get_hash_key();
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



     SharedPreferences sf_shared_pref = getSharedPreferences("variable", 0);
        Boolean on_time_login = sf_shared_pref.getBoolean("flag", false);

        if (on_time_login) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }

           // AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

            fbbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbtn);

            fbbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Call private method
                    onFblogin();
                }
            });

            email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
            pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

            tac1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cAcc);

            tac1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                                    {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {


                                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, RegistrationForm.class));


                                        }
                                    }

            );

            login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lbtn);
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                    eml = email.getText().toString();
                    pswrd = pass.getText().toString();


                    // new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_create_book,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("variable", MODE_PRIVATE); // 0 - for private mode
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                      editor.putBoolean("flag", true);
                    editor.apply();

                                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));
                                        //your intent code here
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username/password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("email", eml);
                            params.put("password", pswrd);

                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

                }

            });
        }


        public void Get_hash_key() {
            PackageInfo info;
            try {
                info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.zeba.broccoli", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md;
                    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                    //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                    Log.e("hash key", something);
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("exception", e.toString());
            }
        }




        private void onFblogin() {
            callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            // Set permissions
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            try {
                                if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                                    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                                        @Override
                                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                                            // profile2 is the new profile
                                            profile = profile_new;
                                            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                                        }
                                    };
                                    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
                                } else {
                                    profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                }

                                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                                Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                                                // Application code
                                                try {
                                                    String fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                                    String fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                                    String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                                    String fb_gender = object.getString("gender");
                                                    String fb_email = object.getString("email");
                                                    String fb_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }

                                                //use shared preferences here
                                            }
                                        });
                                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
                                request.setParameters(parameters);
                                request.executeAsync();


                                //go to Home page
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                            }
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Log.d(TAG_CANCEL, "On cancel");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                            //Log.d(TAG_ERROR, error.toString());
                        }



                        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                            callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                        }
                    });




        }



        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Replace CommonVarilable.LoginPref with you own varialble

Comment: instead use your own variable whatever you assign

Comment: i have email, pass as string variable shud i put this there instead of commonVariable??

Comment: yaa you can instead of boolean replace with string and check if exist at top

Comment: which variable shud i put...when i am trying to put eml, pass which is declared globally then still it showing me error

Comment: it says expected actual found arguments when i applied( email,pass,0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132155/discussion-between-z-al-and-m-yogeshwaran).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CommonUtilities {

    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static Context mContext;

/**
     * Create SharedPreference and SharedPreferecne Editor for Context
     *
     * @param context
     */
    private static void createSharedPreferenceEditor(Context context) {
        try {
            if (context != null) {
                mContext = context;
            } else {
                mContext = ApplicationStore.getContext();
            }
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(IAdoddleConstants.ADODDLE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

/**
 * Put String in SharedPreference Editor
 *
 * @param context
 * @param key
 * @param value
 */
public static void putPrefString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    try {
        createSharedPreferenceEditor(context);
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: where to put this in my code ..can u replace it with my code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use "**SharedPreferences**". 
When a user logs into the application, save a boolean variable say: "USERLOGGED_IN" into the shared preferences, like this:

The below code is to be written inside "AsyncTask":

```
 SharedPreferences prefs;
Editor editor = prefs.edit();<br></br>
        editor .putBoolean("USERLOGGED_IN",true); //If user has logged in successfully<br></br>
//or
        editor .putBoolean("USERLOGGED_IN",false);//If user has not logged in<br></br>
editor.commit();
```

Once the value has been saved in the "SharedPreferences", the only thing left is to check this value, when a user opens the application again.
 Then do this:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs;
boolean USERLOGGED_IN  = prefs.getBoolean("USERLOGGED_IN"); // the value you saved during logging in the user.
if(USERLOGGED_IN == true)
{
    //User has logged in already, so direct the user to home screen.
}
else
{
    //User is new, so direct the user to login screen.
}
```

I hope this helps.